# Wavelet signal decomposition in Octave

Tags: signal-processing, octave, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I want to conduct signal decomposition using wavelet transformation in Octave. And I don't know, what I should do.

I was looking for any black-box functions in Octave, but haven't found anything useful. As far as I know there is `dwt` function in signal package, but I have no idea how to use it. In documentation it says, that:

```
Function File: [u, v] = dwt (x, wname)
```

> From documentation:
>   **x** Signal vector.
>   **wname** Wavelet name.

But when I try to use it this way, octave says

```
error: Invalid call to dwt.  Correct usage is:

 -- Function File: [CA CD] = dwt( X,LO_D,HI_D)
```

Where should I get to `LO_D` and `HI_D` coeffs? Documentation says, that these are "Coefficients of low-pass/high-pass decomposition FIR filter."

And, provided, that I will calculate the dwt on my data, what should I do next to perform the decomposition?

Alternatively, could You provide me with some information, how to perform any decomposition on a signal?

Comment: I think the coefficients can be derived depending on the wavelet name based on the [matlab interface](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/wavelet/ref/dwt.html) but when I do `dwt(ones(1,10), 'sym4')` for instance, octave complains that wfilters is undefined, and I could not find it.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the excellent [Large Time/Frequency Analysis Toolbox](http://ltfat.sourceforge.net/), http://ltfat.sourceforge.net/doc/wavelets/index.php in your case.